# Append bytes to string in python

Tags: python, string, bytebuffer

I have bytes array as str and want to send it (if I look at it through a debugger, it shows me that `File.body` is `str`). For that reason I have to create message to send.

```
request_text += '\n'.join([
    '',
    '--%s' % boundary_id,
    attachment_headers,
    File.body,
])
```

But at only it tries to join file body, I receive exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Still, in [example](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/attachment/ticket/350/soap_attachments.2.py) where I took it, it was implemented this way. How should I order python string to work byte string? Do I should decode it somehow? But how, if that is not text, but just bytes.

Comment: Seems like it's unicode. Is it Python 2 or 3?

Comment: But debugger shows body parameter as {str}

Comment: What is in `attachment_headers` here? What type is `boundary_id`? What type is `request_text`?

Comment: does `'\n'.encode('latin-1').join([ ...` work?

Comment: You are mixing `unicode` and `str` and Python tried to decode an encoded bytestring containing non-ASCII data; make sure your data is either all encoded or all Unicode.

Comment: @Will: That'll **not** make a difference. In Python 2 `'\n'` is **already** encoded. You'll convert a byte string to a unicode string (implicit decoding) then encode *back to a byte string again*.

Comment: @Will: besides, the OP has already shown that `File.body` is of type `str`; it is the **other** types we need to worry about here.

Comment: @Arkady `str` type in Python 2 stands also for binary string, so the type of `File.body` it's not an issue here. Either `attachment_headers` or `boundary_id` is `unicode` here.

Comment: You were right, there was quite hard code creating all those parameters, but once it tried to add unicode, so, all request_text become unicode, and that is why File.body that was {str} couldn't be joined.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the error as your string has non-ascii characters. The following is an example on how to encode/decode a string containing non-ascii characters

1) convert the string to unicode

`string="helloé"
 u=unicode(string, 'utf-8')`

2) Encode the string to utf-8 before sending it on the network

`encoded = u.encode('utf-8')`

3) Decode it from utf-8 to unicode on the other side

`encoded.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: How is your code related to the code in the question? Where is the assignment to variable named `string`? Advising to apply encoding or decoding to some undisclosed variable is not very helpful. IMHO the question is unanswerable because of lack of relevant information about values stored in variables.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, I guess you are right, still, comments behind question was helpful. Before them I look wrong side, searching way for string + bytes appending, after - I checked all incoming strings for being unicode, found one, fixed and that solved my problem.

Comment: I apologize I did post this in the morning in a hurry. The above was intended to be an example on how to encode/decode on a string that has unicode characters for example the `é` in the string s. I will edit my response.